# What makes this code faster?

Tags: matlab

I am implementing the First Fit (FF) heuristic for 1-Dimensional Bin Packing Problem (BPP) in Matlab.

After a first implementation of the algorithm, I tried to improve my code and I ended up with a second implementation that I thought to be better, since it was pretty much more *elegant* in my opinion.

My curiosity (let me say I'm a perfectionist) lead me to run and compare both implementations. They arrived exactly to the same result (as it should be), but my first implementation was more than 10 times faster!

My question is: Can you help me find why is that? What part of the second implementation is slowing down my code?

1st implementation:

```
function packing = firstFit(items)

global N_items bin_size

item_assign = zeros(N_items,1);
residual = bin_size*ones(N_items,1);
tmp = residual;

% Assign each item on the list to a bin
for i = 1:N_items
    j = 1; % always start by trying the first bin
    % Repeat until the item is assigned to a bin
    while true
        if items(i) > residual(j)
            j = j+1; % try to fit it in the next bin 
        else
            residual(j) = residual(j)-items(i);
            item_assign(i) = j;
            break
        end
    end
end

% Check how many bins were needed to accommodate all items
N_bins = N_items - sum(residual == tmp);

packing = cell(N_bins,3);
for i = 1:N_bins
    packing{i,1} = item_assign == i;
    packing{i,2} = items(packing{i,1});
    packing{i,3} = residual(i);
end

end
```

2nd implementation:

```
function packing = firstFit2(items)

global N_items bin_size

% Initialize 1st bin
packing{1,1} = false(N_items,1);
packing{1,3} = bin_size;
N_bins = 1;

% Assign each item on the list to a bin
for i = 1:N_items
    % Look for the first bin able to hold this item
    j = find(cell2mat(packing(:,3)) >= items(i),1);
    if isempty(j)
        % Create a new empty bin if necessary
        j = N_bins + 1;
        packing{j,1} = false(N_items,1);
        packing{j,3} = bin_size;
        N_bins = j;
    end
    % Assign item to that bin
    packing{j,1}(i) = true;
    packing{j,2} = [packing{j,2};items(i)];
    packing{j,3} = packing{j,3} - items(i);
end

end
```

*Results:*

For a given dataset, I got a runtime of about 0.011 seconds for the first implementation while the second one took around 0.13 seconds to complete.

If you want, I can provide you the dataset, just let me know.

*A brief description of the BPP:*

There is a set of items having a characteristic length each. These items should be packed into a set of bins of a fixed size. The goal is to use as few bins as possible to pack all the items.

*A brief description of the FF heuristic:*

The idea behind the First-Fit (FF) heuristic is very simple:

1. items are considered sequentially and each of them is located into the first bin that can accommodate it.
2. A bin is initialized with residual capacity R=C, and when an item is arranged into it, the residual capacity is decreased by the size of that item.
3. If none of the open bins can accommodate an item, a new empty bin is created.

Comment: I dare say it's the allocation time. On the first solution, the bins are created all at once `packing = cell(N_bins,3);`, On the second one, you create them one by one. It may look harmless, but every time you expand the limit of `packing`, a new block of memory capable of holding all the data must be allocated, then the content of the old `packing` must be copied to the new one.

Comment: Use the matlab command `profile` to analyse the performance.

Comment: And simpler code may be easier to JIT optimize – especially when multiple loops are involved. I wonder if all of the calls to `cell2mat` might also hinder performance ... the profiler will tell you these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. It's not easy to say why one implementation is faster than the other because MATLAB does a variety of optimizations behind the scenes. Loops, and especially changing the size of a vector inside a loop (as you do in the second code) are generally slow.

The clean MATLAB way of doing this looks like

```
%% do the actual work
binSize = 20;
itemMaxSize = 10;
numItems = 10;

items = randi(itemMaxSize, numItems, 1);

R = binSize * ones(numItems, 1); % there can not be more bins than items
assignment = zeros(numItems, 1);

for i = 1:numItems
    assignment(i) = find( R >= items(i), 1, 'first');
    R(assignment(i)) = R(assignment(i)) - items(i);

end

R = R( R < binSize );

%% make a figure
figure
hold on
for i = 1:length(R)
    itemInds = find(assignment == i);
    sizes = items(itemInds);

    plot(i, cumsum(sizes), '*')
    text(i * ones(size(sizes)) + .1, cumsum(sizes), num2str(itemInds))
end


ylim([0 round(binSize*1.1)])
plot([.5 length(R)+.5], [binSize binSize], '--')
xlim([.5, length(R)+.5]);
set(gca, 'xtick', 1:length(R))
xlabel('bin ind')
ylabel('fill')
```